# Why would doing the "outlet challenge" cause notable damage to outlet and wiring?

Tags: safety, wiring, short-circuit, circuit-protection, power-grid

**WARNING!!! WHAT "PRANKERS" IN THE VIDEO DO IS MOST LIKELY VERY DANGEROUS AND MAY CAUSE DEATH, INJURY, FIRE OR OTHER DAMAGES AND IT SHOULD NOT BE TRIED IN ANY ELECTRICAL SETUPS WHICH ARE NOT DESIGNED SPECIFICALLY FOR DOING SUCH EXPERIMENTS**

The video at the bottom shows how young people plug a phone charger into a generic USA fashion (two flat prongs) outlet but don't push the charger until it touches the outlet surface and instead leave a small gap between the charger and the outlet surface. Then they drop a coin onto the charger prongs which causes a short circuit condition because now most of the current flows through the prongs and the coin. The short causes a flash, a pop sound and some smoke. The short also causes the circuit breaker to disconnect the outlet.

On 01:09 the video shows the outlet internals burnt and melted and it's attributed to causing the short as explained above. Why did it get so much damage? I was under impression that the purpose of a circuit breaker is to promptly disconnect the circuit when a short develops. So a pop sound, a flash and maybe some smoke are no surprise but a melted outlet is rather unexpected.

Why does a short cause so much damage in a circuit protected by a circuit breaker.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5XJ1RThaVw

Answer (score 2):

If there is a bad connection (loose wire connection to outlet or dirty coin) instead of full short circuit, there is enough resistance that a lot of current flows but not enough to trip the breaker. And when power goes into resistance, it heats up. And the heating happens at the outlet, melting the plastic. The circuit breaker could be faulty too, passing much more current than intended before breaking, or fails to break at all.

Answer (score 1):

The plug prongs aren't properly seated between the contacts in the outlet.  That means high resistance in the contacts, so the heating is local.  It burns the contacts and melts stuff in the outlet.

Because of the (relatively) high resistance between the outlet contacts and the plug pins, the circuit breaker never sees enough current flow to trip.

In other words, it isn't a full on short circuit so the breaker doesn't trip.

---

When I was a kid, I made "electrobombs" that consisted of a short piece of very thin wire in a small container.  The wire was connected to a 110VAC power cable. Plugging it into an outlet would vaporize the wire and cause the container to pop.  The breaker mostly didn't trip, but I'm pretty sure the outlet was ruined.  I know that the plug on the power cable got pretty messed up - the prongs got all burned and rough on the tips.  That's much like the situation in the "outlet challenge," except in my case the short circuit removed itself after a very short time.